# How to make Growl notifications with Adobe Air?

Tags: javascript, html, css, air

I just started to develop Air applications with HTML/CSS/JS.

And i was wondering: What is the easiest way to make Growl notifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can talk to growl directly using sockets. I only found an example of this in PHP, but you should be able to convert that to actionscript pretty easity pretty. You'll need the sample code from [here](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/php-growl/). However I'm not sure the socket api is officially supported by growl... so it may be subject to change over tiem.

You may also be able to use fscommand with "exec" to run the command line growl system. (I have a feeling that fscommand has been switched to something else in newer versions of flash though...)

Answer (score 1):

You can get away with growl-like notifications using HTML/CSS/JS like so:

http://www.thedevshack.com/growl-type-notifications-in-adobe-air/

Note that the example doesn't include handling for actually adjusting the notification messages.

### EDIT: A Better Solution

The source code to the Twitter client Spaz is open sourced. It contains some very clever handling for creating both growl and growl-esque notifications. Here's some of the core files related to growl notifications to get you started:

- https://github.com/funkatron/spaz-desktop-air/blob/master/vendors/purrjs.js
- https://github.com/funkatron/spaz-desktop-air/blob/master/vendors/SpazGrowl.js
- https://github.com/funkatron/spaz-desktop-air/blob/master/vendors/as3growl.swf
- https://github.com/funkatron/spaz-desktop-air/blob/master/bin/growlnotify

Spaz also includes **Mac OSX Growl** notifications via [as3growl](http://code.google.com/p/as3growl/).